# Ubuntu Server 18.04 - automatic fallback to stable kernel after crash

Tags: server, grub2, 18.04, kernel, crash

I am administrating a remote server and I am trying to verify if is possible to have a scenario when if it crashes after an update it resets and goes back to boot via the previous stable kernel (basically it falls back to the previous stable kernel). Is this possible to do via Grub in Ubuntu 18.04?

I have checked around but I could not identify a clean solution to do this in Ubuntu Server 18.04.

We had a problem with an unstable kernel recently and it had to be solved locally; since the server is in a different country we would prefer to avoid this scenario.